# How to handle authentication in hybrid ASP.NET and PHP website?

Tags: php, asp.net, codeigniter, authentication, kentico

I am taking over a community website that was built using Kentico (an ASP.NET-based CMS).

I have PHP/CodeIgniter code that could add interesting functionality to this Kentico website. For example, my PHP code allows for uploading and posting of user-generated material such as images, which the community can then comment on.

Since I'm unfamiliar with how Kentico works, I wonder if anyone knows if this functionality exists in it (as a module). If not, either this

- would have to be coded in ASP.NET or
- I could have a hybrid website using my PHP code, however authentication from the Kentico side would have to be passed the PHP side of the website.

Any suggestions on how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the authenticated session in the DB where both ASP and PHP have access

Comment: thanks - would this be better than pulling the auth from cookie?

Comment: The cookie stores a "key" to the autentication data. You are not actually storing the autenthication data in the cookie but you store it inside a session. So the key remains in the cookie for both ASP and PHP. But the actual authentication data is server side and you need to store it in a common place and format to be accessible by both languages. Most common place would be a database.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the "User contributions module" - if you've got access to a new enough version of Kentico and the appropriate license then it will probably do exactly what you need it to.

Otherwise if you needed to do authentication from a seperate PHP app, I suppose you could write a simple web service in .Net and add it into the Kentico site. In the past I've used a .ashx generic handler to do this. 
Maybe you could include a hidden iframe to the other site on each page and use postMessage in JavaScript to send a session ID between the sites.

I would probably try to keep everything all in one code base unless there was reason to break it out into a seperate module though - otherwise it just seems like a lot of extra work.